# Get List of Entity Objects with Input List : Spring Data JPA - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a List of APIObjects `List<APIObjects> apiObjectList` as an Input to my API (through HTTP-Post), I need to check all the parameters within this Object exists in my Database

**DatabaseObject.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class DatabaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    String groupId;

    @Column(name = "artifact_id")
    String artifactId;

    @Column(name = "version")
    String version;
 }
```

**APIObject.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class APIObject{
    private String groupId;
    private String artifactId;
    private String version;
}
```

In my `Repository Interface` i have a method like this

```
List<DatabaseObject> findByGroupIdAndArtifactIdAndVersionIn (List<APIobject> apiList);
```

But i get this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter available for part artifactId SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals].
```

How to write a `Spring-data-JPA` method for this ? All the three parameters should match `(groupid, artifactid and version)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a query from method names, you should change the repository method:

```java
List<DatabaseObject> findByGroupIdAndArtifactIdAndVersion(String groupId, String artifactId, String version);
```

Or with `In` keyword:

```java
List<DatabaseObject> findByAPIobjectIn(Collection<APIObject> apis)
```

See [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. The `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` is in a list. Do you mean to say that I need to iterate that list and start firing queries individually ? Suppose if i get a big list, individual query firing seems to be a costly solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) technique.
In your case the solution may look like this:

```
DatabaseObject dbObject = new DatabaseObject(apiObject.getGroupId(), ...);
Iterable<DatabaseObject> dbObjects = DatabaseObjectRepository.findAll(Example.of(dbObject));
```

Comment: How to give a `list of APIObject` and ensure all the `groupid-artifactid-version` is there in the table